# String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '')

Tags: java, android

String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '').. here is the block that gives me the problem (the parent="" is where the problem occurs)

```
<style
 name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent="">
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
<item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">?android:textColorHint</item>
```

Comment: Set the value in `parent` or remove the `parent` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

remove the parent attribute.or write parent="true"

Comment: doesn't work for me